System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization nuget package is not working in .Net 6 Framewrok ,
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization was working fine in .net 4.8 , We have recently moved from 4.8 to .6 however when try run the application it come with an error "Error: Could not load file or assembly '"
we get an errro "Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Added the correct refrence assmebly
Updated Windows Forms support
Updated NuGet Packages
Clean and Rebuild
Ensure the target to Any CPU


.NET 6 is .NET Core 6. System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization itself is very old and was essentially abandoned as MS moved to WPF, then WinRT, WinUI, MAUI etc. It's deprecated was never officially ported to .NET Core. The duplicate question points to a package that ported the old code to work on .NET Core and the new Forms designer

Does this answer your question? Creating a chart in C# WinForms .NET 6

I suspect the real question, and the reason the DataVisualization library was used, is where to find free chart tools for WinForms. There are far better solutions now, both paid and free. The Awesome .NET WinForms page has a list of components and libraries that work with WinForms in .NET Core. One of them is a clone of DataVisualization. Others are completely new
